# Flask issue CORS Origin

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to call my API with my front end and I have this following error :

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at '*' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.`

Strange because according to the documentation I just need add this in my `app.py` :

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = "Content-Type"
app.config['CORS_RESOURCES'] = {r"*": {"origins": "*"}}
app.register_blueprint(node_blueprint, url_prefix='/api/v1/sample')

cors = CORS(app)
```

But I have `blueprint` so in my blueprint I have :

```
@api.route('/', methods=["GET"])
@cross_origin()
def get:
  ...

@api.after_request
def set_cors_header(response):
  response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  return response
```

Can you explain me ?

Answer (score 1):

Dont know if this will help you, but i had a similar problem a while ago. I added the following:

In my CORS (since my api uses credentials):

```
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)
```

Then my headers :

```
response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
                "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-auth")
response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
                'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE')
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for you're answer but not working for me :(